# No me muestra el interior de un directorio que específico

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

tengo un codigo linux bash en el que especifico que me abra el contenido de un directorio, sin embargo me pone, por ejemplo *"ls: no se puede acceder a './/lib/apache2/modules': No existe el archivo o el directorio"* ¿Como que no existe?, si estoy especificando la ruta de acceso y todo. La idea es que me muestre el contenido, las carpetas o lo que fuera que tenga dicho directorio, pero no lo hace.

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo "Pedir tres cadenas por teclado";
read -p "Dime una string:" string1;
read -p "Dime otra string:" string2;
read -p "Dime otra string mas:" string3;

if [ -d "$string1" ];
then
  cd "$directorio"
  echo ""
  echo "La cadena1 es el nombre de un directorio.."
  echo "Su contenido ($string1):"

  ls ./"$string1"
else
  echo "ERROR: La cadena1 no corresponde al nombre de ningun directorio."
fi



if [ -d "$string2" ];
then
  cd "$directorio"
  echo ""
  echo "La cadena2 es el nombre de un directorio."
  echo "Su contenido ($string2):"

  ls ./"$string2"
else
  echo "ERROR: La cadena2 no corresponde al nombre de ningun directorio."
fi




if [ -d "$string3" ];
then
  cd "$directorio"
  echo ""
  echo "La cadena3 es el nombre de un directorio."
  echo "His content ($string3):"

  ls ./"$string3"
else
  echo "ERROR: La cadena3 no corresponde al nombre de ningun directorio."
fi
```

PD: Dejo otro ejemplo mas visual, con una imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es que a `ls` le añades un `./` inicial innecesario, pues después le das una ruta absoluta.

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurren algo que probar...
Cuando ejecutas el comando de listado `ls`, prueba a quitar el comando de ejecutable `./`. Si sólo quieres que te liste el contenido de un directorio basta con el comando `ls`

Tuyo:

```
ls ./"$string1"
```

Prueba:

```
ls "$string1"
```

Comment: Correcto, estoy empanadisimo y lograba ver dicho error, ¡muchísimas gracias!